# Maximum Number of Request Parameters for fetchAll()

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch

Is there a maximum number of fetch requests that can be made in a single call to `URLFetchApp.fetchAll()`? I have limited experience with AppScripts and could not find anything on the docs indicating that there is a limit on the number of requests, but I'm curious to see if a limit does exist. Any input is welcome.

Comment: In my environment, I confirmed that 1,000 requests can be worked. [Ref](https://tanaikech.github.io/2018/04/19/benchmark-fetchall-method-in-urlfetch-service-for-google-apps-script/) But, I think that this situation might depend on the specification of the server side which is requested with the fetchAll method.

Answer (score 3):

#### Answer:

*Expanding on the research undertaken by [Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike) in his [benchmarking research for `UrlFetchApp.fetchAll()`](https://tanaikech.github.io/2018/04/19/benchmark-fetchall-method-in-urlfetch-service-for-google-apps-script/). I was able to make 2199 requests successfully, but more triggered a rate limit on the endpoint so I was unable to test furhter.*

#### Research:

After reading the aforementioned benchmark, I took to Apps Script to see if I could find a limit for the method. I used [httpbin](https://httpbin.org/) for testing, as this is what is provided by Google in the example snippet for [`fetchAll(requests)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchallrequests):

```
// Make both a POST request with form data, and a GET request.
var resumeBlob = Utilities.newBlob('Hire me!', 'text/plain', 'resume.txt');
var formData = {
  'name': 'Bob Smith',
  'email': 'bob@example.com',
  'resume': resumeBlob
};
// Because payload is a JavaScript object, it is interpreted as
// as form data. (No need to specify contentType; it defaults to either
// 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' or 'multipart/form-data')
var request1 = {
  'url': 'https://httpbin.org/post',
  'method' : 'post',
  'payload' : formData
};
// A request may also just be a URL.
var request2 = 'https://httpbin.org/get?key=value';
UrlFetchApp.fetchAll([request1, request2]);
```

I modified this by initialising an array of length `n` and populating it with requests like so:

```
function fetchAllTester() {
  var resumeBlob = Utilities.newBlob('Hire me!', 'text/plain', 'resume.txt');
  var formData = {
    'name': 'Bob Smith',
    'email': 'bob@example.com',
    'resume': resumeBlob
  }

  var request1 = {
    'url': 'https://httpbin.org/post',
    'method' : 'post',
    'payload' : formData
  }

  let requests = new Array(1000).fill(request1)

  UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(requests).map(x => console.log(x.getContentText()))
}
```

I started with 1000 as this has already been confirmed to work. The results were then as follows:

- 2000 requests - worked
- 2500 requests - `HTTP 502` returned by httpbin.
- 2001 requests - worked
- 2100 requests - worked
- 2200 requests - `HTTP 502` returned by httpbin.
- 2199 requests - worked
- 2199 requests - `HTTP 502` returned by httpbin.

At this point sending 2199 requests seemed to be intermittantly responsive, but with an HTTP 502: Bad Gateway error which pointed to the problem coming from outside of the `fetchAll()` method.

#### Conclusion:

It appears that is a limit on `UrlFetchApp.fetchAll()` exists, then it is high.

From the [Quotas for Google Services page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas), the only limit on calls that is listed is:

> | Feature | Consumer (e.g., gmail.com) and G Suite free edition ([legacy](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2855120)) | Google Workspace accounts |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | URL Fetch calls | 20,000 / day | 100,000 / day |

My assumption therefore, based on the testing I have done and the documentation provided by Google, is that the method is limited only by regular Apps Script Quotas; that is to say, 20,000 requests per day for consumer accounts and 100,000 requests per day for Workspace accounts.

#### References:

- [Benchmark: fetchAll method in UrlFetch service for Google Apps Script - tanaikech.github.io](https://tanaikech.github.io/2018/04/19/benchmark-fetchall-method-in-urlfetch-service-for-google-apps-script/)
- [Class UrlFetchApp - fetchAll(requests) | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchallrequests)
- [Quotas for Google Services | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)